SSRS 2012 to SSRS 2019 upgrade with forms authentication
I have a client that is wanting to migrate to SQL 2019 from 2012. That upgrade path as you all know de couples SSRS from the SQL upgrade. The problem that I am having is that migrating the SSRS to 2019 around forms based authentication, their 2012 setup uses forms based auth for login. I have tried several times to migrate this and am running into problems. I have installed 2019 SSRS and assigned it the correct virtual directories and it upgrades the SSRS database fine, then i restored the encryption keys successfully and stopped services. I copied the aspx login page as well as the dll and pdb files to both reportserver/bin and /portal directories and then edited rsreportserver.config file and web.config file but when i start the services and try to access the url I always get an http 500 error.
I am at intermediate level on SSRS here and need help to get the forms auth working. what am I missing?

What does the different SSRS log files say the specific error is?
